# How to read data from BigQuery periodically in Apache Beam?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to read data from Bigquery periodically in Beam, and the test codes as below

```java
pipeline.apply("Generate Sequence",
            GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardMinutes(2)))
    .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(2))))
    .apply("Read from BQ", new ReadBQ())
    .apply("Convert Row",
            MapElements.into(TypeDescriptor.of(MyData.class)).via(MyData::fromTableRow))
    .apply("Map TableRow", ParDo.of(new MapTableRowV1()))
    ;


static class ReadBQ extends PTransform<PCollection<Long>, PCollection<TableRow>> {
    @Override
    public PCollection<TableRow> expand(PCollection<Long> input) {
        BigQueryIO.TypedRead<TableRow> rows = BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
            .fromQuery("select * from project.dataset.table limit 10")
            .usingStandardSql();
        return rows.expand(input.getPipeline().begin()); 
    }
}

static class MapTableRowV1 extends DoFn<AdUnitECPM, Void> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext pc) {
        LOG.info("String of mydata is " + pc.element().toString());
    }
}
```

[image]

Since `BigQueryIO.TypedRead` is related to `PBegin`, one trick is done in `ReadBQ` through `rows.expand(input.getPipeline().begin())`. However, this job does NOT run every two minutes. How to read data from bigquery periodically?

Comment: Note how the GenerateSequence box has 4 hours of CPU time when the Read form BQ haas 7 secs. I tried this solution and it hogged all my CPU.

Answer (score 2):

Look at using [Looping Timers](https://beam.apache.org/blog/looping-timers/). That provides the right pattern.

As written your code would only fire once after sequence is built. For fixed windows you would need an input value coming into the Window for it to trigger. For example, have the pipeline read a Pub/Sub input and then have an agent push events every 2 minutes into the topic/sub.

I am going to assume that you are running in streaming mode here; however, another way to do this would be to use a batch job and then run it every 2 mins from Composer. Reason being if your job is idle for effectively 90 secs (2 min - processing time) your streaming job wasting some resources.

One other note: Look at thinning down you column selection in your BigQuery SQL (to save time and money). Look at using some filter on your SQL to pick up a partition or cluster. Look at using @timestamp filter to only scan records that are new in last N. This could give you better control over how you deal with latency and variability at the db level.

Comment: It seems there is some typo in Looping Timers, there is no variable `timeRunning` in the code snippet.

Comment: The method `set` of TimerSpec is removed since beam 2.23.0?

Answer (score 2):

As you have mentioned in the question, BigQueryIO read transforms start with PBegin, which puts it at the start of the Graph. In order to achieve what you are looking for, you will need to make use of the BigQuery client libraries directly within a DoFn.

For an example of this have a look at this
[transform](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataflow-sample-applications/blob/master/retail/retail-java-applications/data-engineering-dept/business-logic/src/main/java/com/google/dataflow/sample/retail/businesslogic/externalservices/SlowMovingStoreLocationDimension.java)

Using a normal DoFn for this will be ok for small amounts of data, but for a large amount of data, you will want to look at implementing that logic in a [SDF](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AQmx-T9XjSi1PNoEp5_L-lT0j7BkgTbmQnc6uFEMI4c/edit#).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have implemented it with BigQuery client libraries. Out of curiosity, why BigQueryIO read transforms start with PBegin? what if it does not start with PBegin?

Comment: If I recall a readAll was being looked at as part of this:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-9650

Answer (score 0):

Per the [transform](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataflow-sample-applications/blob/master/retail/retail-java-applications/data-engineering-dept/business-logic/src/main/java/com/google/dataflow/sample/retail/businesslogic/externalservices/SlowMovingStoreLocationDimension.java) given by @Reza Rokni. The bigquery client could be used in the `DoFn` to return `TableRow` directly
under beam version `2.23`.

Here are one sample codes.

```java
    static class ReadBQParDo extends DoFn<Long, TableRow> {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
            BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
            QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig =
                    QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query)
                            .setUseLegacySql(false)
                            .build();

            JobId jobId = JobId.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            Job queryJob = bigquery.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryConfig).setJobId(jobId).build());

            // Wait for the query to complete.
            queryJob = queryJob.waitFor();
            if (queryJob == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Job no longer exists");
            } else if (queryJob.getStatus().getError() != null) {
                throw new RuntimeException(queryJob.getStatus().getError().toString());
            }

            TableResult result = queryJob.getQueryResults();
            for (FieldValueList row : result.iterateAll()) {
                c.output(row);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Unfortunately, the bigquery client could not found under beam `2.46` and the `bigquery` and `TableResult` could NOT be found in this version. In order to return `TableRow` in the `DoFn`, we could build `bigquery` client refer to [`BigqueryClient`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/testing/BigqueryClient.java), here are sample codes.

```java
  public static Bigquery getNewBigqueryClient(String applicationName) {
    HttpTransport transport = Transport.getTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = Transport.getJsonFactory();
    Credentials credential = getDefaultCredential();
    return new Bigquery.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credential))
        .setApplicationName(applicationName)
        .build();
  }

   static class ReadBQParDo extends DoFn<Long, TableRow> {
        @ProcessElement
        public TableRow processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
            TableReference tempTableReference =
                    new TableReference().setProjectId(projectId).setDatasetId(datasetId).setTableId(tableId);

            JobConfigurationQuery jcQuery =
                    new JobConfigurationQuery()
                            .setFlattenResults(false)
                            .setAllowLargeResults(true)
                            .setDestinationTable(tempTableReference)
                            .setUseLegacySql(true)
                            .setQuery(query);
            JobConfiguration jc = new JobConfiguration().setQuery(jcQuery);

            Job job = new Job().setConfiguration(jc);

            Job queryJob = bqClient.jobs().insert(projectId, job).execute();

            GetQueryResultsResponse qResponse;
            do {
                qResponse = bqClient.jobs()
                                .getQueryResults(projectId, queryJob.getJobReference().getJobId())
                                .execute();
            } while (!qResponse.getJobComplete());

            final List<TableRow> rows = qResponse.getRows();
            for (TableRow row: rows) {
                c.output(row);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```